# pandas current row * previous row +previous row

Tags: python, pandas

index_pd:

```
tradedate  |  percent  |  day_index
------ | ------| ------
2015-06-02 |    0      |     1000
2015-06-03 |    0.5    |     0
2015-06-04 |    0.6    |     0
.....
```

want result:

```
tradedate  |  percent  |  day_index
------ | ------| ------
2015-06-02 |    0      |     1000
2015-06-03 |    0.5    |     1500 = 1000 + 1000 * 0.5
2015-06-04 |    0.6    |     2400 = 1500 + 1500 * 0.6
.....
```

i try

```
index_pd['day_index'] =index_pd['day_index'].shift(1) * index_pd['percent'].shift(0) + index_pd['day_index'].shift(1)
```

but it effect second row.
there are thousand rows in index_pd, how to batch replace,thanks

Comment: You'll need to write to a different column if you want to keep the original value of the second row.

Comment: how can i batch Calculation?

Comment: What do you mean by batch? My original answer isn't even right, you should be writing the result to day index and using the result to calculate the next step.

Comment: @TLOwater use for to getting pre day_index and save current result?

Answer (score 2):

Not very nice solution, because loop by [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
for i, row in index_pd.iterrows():
    if i == 0:
        index_pd.loc[i, 'value'] = index_pd['day_index'].iat[0]
    else:
        index_pd.loc[i, 'value'] = index_pd.loc[i,'percent']  * index_pd.loc[i-1, 'value']+ \
                                   index_pd.loc[i-1, 'value']
print (index_pd)
    tradedate  percent  day_index   value
0  2015-06-02      0.0       1000  1000.0
1  2015-06-03      0.5          0  1500.0
2  2015-06-04      0.6          0  2400.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In every row of your calculation the previous `day_index` value gets multiplied by `(1+index_pd.percent)`. So you can use a cumulative product of `(1+index_pd.percent)` and multiply that by the first value of `day_index` to obtain the result:

```
index_pd['day_index'] = (index_pd.percent+1).cumprod()*index_pd.day_index.iat[0]
```